# django rest framework - How to POST nested object with parent object

Tags: post, django-rest-framework, relation

I have parent object order and nested object orderDetail.

```
class Order(Model):
     order_name = CharField(max_length=10)

class OrderDetails(Model):
     order_detail_name = CharField(max_length=10)
     order = ForeignKey('Order')
```

I want to get/insert/update/delete OrderDetails with order object itself.
If I post this json, it should insert/update both objects.

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "order_name": "Some title",
    "orderDetails": [{
         "id": 15,
         "order_detail_name": "Best Detail"
     }]
}
```

Thats all. not able to find out any solution. I'm beginner to django/python.

TIA

Comment: anyone can plz help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved get problem by my self using simpler two liner.

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   orderdetail_set = OrderDetailSerializer(many=true)
```

POST

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    order_details_data = validated_data.pop('orderdetail_set')
    order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)

    for order_detail_data in order_details_data:
        order_detail_data['order'] = order
        OrderDetail.objects.create(**order_detail_data)
    return order
```

Now its giving response as expected. :)

Comment: I can't POST several children in one request, I get the `"Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."` error message. As if although I have a many to one relationship like you between the parent and the child models, I can't pass a list in the parent object for the children. Have you done anything special to handle that, or have you encountered that error berfore?